# in R data.table using as.numeric as 0 or 1 value producer coerces NA where should not

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, data.table

In R data.table I have this table:

```
  Company <- c ("A", "A" , "A", "A", "B" , "B", "B", "B")
  TopManger <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
  Salary <- c(300, 300, 300, NA, 250,250, NA, 100)
  tbl = data.table(company, TopManger, Salary)
```

that looks like:

```
    Company TopManger Salary
1:       A         1    300
2:       A         1    300
3:       A         1    300
4:       A         0     NA
5:       B         1    250
6:       B         1    250
7:       B         0     NA
8:       B         0    100
```

I perform this query:

```
tbl[, HighPayedComp := as.numeric(Salary[TopManger == 1] > 200), by=Company]
```

And I expect to get this:

```
   Company TopManger Salary HighPayedComp
1:       A         1    300             1
2:       A         1    300             1
3:       A         1    300             1
4:       A         0     NA             1
5:       B         1    250             1
6:       B         1    250             1
7:       B         0     NA             1
8:       B         0    100             1
```

In this minimal example it works but in my big data.table in some arbitrary but fixed situations coerces `NA` where logically it shouldn't:
For example in line 5 I have `NA` for `HighPayedComp`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it more clear what's going on. Describe precisely the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be due to the presence of `NA` in the 'TopManager' column.  The `==` returns NA whenever there is a `NA`.  It can be avoided by either using `%in%` or creating another condition with `!is.na`

```
tbl[, HighPayedComp:= as.integer(salary[TopManager == 1 & 
                         !is.na(TopManager)] > 200), by = Company]
```

Or using `%in%`

```
tbl[, HighPayedComp:= as.integer(salary[TopManager %in% 1] > 200), by = Company]
```

---

This is because of the behavior of `==`

```
v1 <- c(NA, 1, 3)
v1 ==1
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE
```

whereas

```
!is.na(v1) & v1==1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

takes care of the `NA` elements

If we use `%in%`, the code is basically doing a `match` and converting it to logical (`> 0L`)

```
`%in%`
#function (x, table) 
#match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
```

In the vector above, the first element is NA and doing the logical comparison with `==` returns NA.

It is also described in the `?"=="`

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even
>   to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.
>   Missing values can also result when character strings are compared and
>   one is not valid in the current collation locale.

#### data

```
tbl <- data.table(Company = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each =2), TopManager = c(1, 0, NA,
  1, 1, NA), salary = c(250, 300, 220, 180, 240, 200))
```

Comment: It works but doesn't make sense to me. In some rows where it coerces unwanted NA, it's not compared to NA.

Comment: You are ignoring recycling. `x[cond] < y` could have any length between `0` and `.N` (in principle) and yet you are assigning it as if it recycles safely.